# How to make a clean Asynchronous loop?

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, loops, asynchronous

Following typical REST standards, I broke up my resources into separate endpoints and calls.  The main two objects in question here are `List` and `Item` (and of course, a list has a list of items, as well as some other data associated with it).

So if a user wants to retrieve his lists, he might make a Get request to `api/Lists`

Then the user might want to get the items in one of those lists and make a Get to `api/ListItems/4` where 4 was found from `List.listId` retrieved in the previous call.

This is all well and good: the `options.complete` attribute of `$.ajax` lets me point to a callback method, so I can streamline these two events.

But things get very messy if I want to get the elements for *all* the lists in question.  For example, let's assume I have a library function called `makeGetRequest` that takes in the end point and callback function, to make this code cleaner. Simply retrieving 3 elements the naive way results in this:

```
var success1 = function(elements){
    var success2 = function(elements){
       makeGetRequest("api/ListItems/3", finalSuccess);
    }
    makeGetRequest("api/ListItems/2", success2);
}
makeGetRequest("api/ListItems/1", success1);
```

**Disgusting!** This is the kind of thing in programming 101 we're smacked across the wrists for and pointed to loops.  But how can you do this with a loop, without having to rely on external storage?

```
for(var i : values){
    makeGetRequest("api/ListItems/" + i, successFunction);
}

function successFunction(items){
    //I am called i-many times, each time only having ONE list's worth of items!
}
```

And even with storage, I would have to know when *all* have finished and retrieved their data, and call some master function that retrieves all the collected data and does something with it.

Is there a practice for handling this? This must have been solved many times before...

Comment: is there a reason you wouldn't have a route on your backend to retrieve all this for you, e.g. `api/ListItems/all` or something similar? then you could avoid the need for any type of async loop.

Answer (score 4):

Try using a stack of endpoint parameters:

```
var params = [];
var results [];

params.push({endpoint: "api/ListItems/1"});
params.push({endpoint: "api/ListItems/2"});
params.push({endpoint: "api/ListItems/3"});
params.push({endpoint: "api/ListItems/4"});
```

Then you can make it recursive in your success handler:

```
function getResources(endPoint) {

   var options = {} // Ajax Options
   options.success = function (data) {
       if (params.length > 0) {
           results.push({endpoint: endpoint, data: data});
           getResources(params.shift().endpoint);
       }
       else {
          theMasterFunction(results)
       }
   }

   $.get(endPoint, options)
}
```

And you can start it with a single call like this:

```
getResources(params.shift().endpoint);
```

**Edit:**

To keep everything self contained and out of global scope you can use a function and provide a callback:

```
function downloadResources(callback) {

    var endpoints = [];
    var results [];

    endpoints.push({endpoint: "api/ListItems/1"});
    endpoints.push({endpoint: "api/ListItems/2"});
    endpoints.push({endpoint: "api/ListItems/3"});
    endpoints.push({endpoint: "api/ListItems/4"});

    function getResources(endPoint) {
        var options = {} // Ajax Options
        options.success = function (data) {
           if (endpoints.length > 0) {
               results.push({endpoint: endpoint, data: data});
               getResources(endpoints.shift().endpoint);
           }
           else {
              callback(results)
           }
        }
       $.get(endPoint, options)
    }

    getResources(endpoints.shift().endpoint);

}
```

In use:

```
downloadResources(function(data) {
   // Do stuff with your data set
});
```

Comment: When iteration fails, go to recursion, eh? A very elegant solution! I still need to find a place to hide away `params` and `results` so that they will not fall out of scope between calls, however. Any suggestions there? I try to avoid the "global variable" cheat.

Comment: @ngmiceli I would suggest a DownloadResources function that contains the endpoints array, you can then provide your continue callback as an argument to this function. See my edit for details.

Answer (score 2):

dmck's answer is probably your best bet. However, another option is to do a bulk list option, so that your api supports requests like api/ListItems/?id=1&id=2&id=3.

You could also do an api search endpoint, if that fits your personal aesthetic more.

Comment: This is a good point, and a very simple solution that I utterly overlooked. Goes along nicely with @jackwanders comment. Give my API the ability to handle a bulk GET, and piece everything together back on the client side. Is this still considered RESTful?

Comment: If you're retrieving data with the GET protocol, then no matter how "pretty" the URL is, then it's RESTful. There is some question as to how that endpoint should work. You call it a "list", where a more appropriate name might be bulklist or search.